# C++ Binary search keywords error

Tags: c++, binary-search

there. I am trying to count keywords in a file using binary search. Yet in some cases the function returns a correct index and in other cases it just cannot get the index. And I don't know why is that. Here is my code:

---

GlobalsDefine.h

```
#pragma once
#define MAXLEN 10   
#define TOTAL 32    
#define HASHLEN 41  

extern const char* KeyWords[TOTAL];
```

---

BiSearch.h

```
#ifndef BISEARCH_H
#define BISEARCH_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include "GlobalsDefine.h"
using namespace std;


class SeqWords
{
public:
    char keyword[MAXLEN];
    int length;
    int count;
};

int BiSearch(char* des, const char** src, int begin, int last);         
void initKeyWords(SeqWords* SW);

#endif // BISEARCH_H
```

---

BiSearch.cpp

```
#include "BiSearch.h"
SeqWords SW[TOTAL];
int BiSearch(char* des, const char** src, int begin, int last)  
{  
    int result = -1;  
    while(begin <= last)  
    {  
        int mid = (begin + last) / 2;  
        if(strcmp(src[mid],des) > 0)  
            last = mid - 1;  
        else if(strcmp(src[mid],des) < 0)  
            begin = mid + 1;  
        else  
        {  
            if(result < mid)  
                result = mid;  
            begin = mid + 1;  
        }  
    }  
    return result;
}  


void initKeyWords(SeqWords* SW)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < TOTAL; i++)
    {
        strcpy(SW[i].keyword,KeyWords[i]);
        SW[i].length = strlen(SW[i].keyword);
        SW[i].count = 0;
    }
}
```

---

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "BiSearch.h"
#include "GlobalsDefine.h"
using namespace std;
const char* KeyWords[TOTAL] = 
{
    "auto","double","int","struct","break","else","long","switch",
    "case","enum","register","typedef","char","extern","return","union",
    "const","float","short","unsigned","continue","for","signed","void",
    "default","goto","sizeof","volatile","do","if","while","static",
};

int main()
{   
    extern SeqWords SW[TOTAL];
    initKeyWords(SW);   
    cout << BiSearch("if", KeyWords, 0, TOTAL) << endl;
    cout << BiSearch("for", KeyWords, 0, TOTAL) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Results:

```
29
-1
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve the issue? Put some `cout` statements in your BiSearch implementation?

Comment: Next to the fact that binary search needs sorted input, there is no need for anything else than return the found result when the searched string is found, so I would expect `else { return mid; }` and definitely not  `if (result < mid)`.

Comment: Thank you for advice and definitely { return mid; } is better.

Answer (score 2):

binary search requires the array to be sorted, which is not your case.

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/dlMie0) with sorted input, and with fixed calling site (`last` is not `TOTAL` but `TOTAL - 1`)

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform the binary search correctly the search vector (KeyWords in your case) must be correctly sorted. And this is not the case in your example, since you have 'break' after 'struct', for example.

Answer (score 1):

Binary Search works on Sorted Arrays only, to make your code work, you need to sort `KeyWords` first.